# what is the difference between dispatch_async_f and dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Whats the difference between

> dispatch_async_f

and

> dispatch_async

in ios?

Comment: Take a look at the docs. dispatch_async_f has an additional parameter. See if you can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dispatch_async -**

Submits a block for asynchronous execution on a dispatch queue and returns immediately.
This function is the fundamental mechanism for submitting blocks to a dispatch queue. Calls to this function always return immediately after the block has been submitted and never wait for the block to be invoked.

**Declaration** : `void dispatch_async( dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block);`

**Params** :
queue - the queue on which block is to be submitted & can’t be NULL.
block - block to be submitted to the target queue & can’t be NULL.

**dispatch_async_f -**

Submits a application defined block for async execution on a dispatch queue & returns immediately.
This function is the fundamental mechanism for submitting application-defined functions to a dispatch queue. Calls to this function always return immediately after the function has been submitted and never wait for it to be invoked.

**Declaration** : `void dispatch_async_f( dispatch_queue_t queue, void *context, dispatch_function_t work);`

**Params** :
queue - the queue on which block is to be submitted & can’t be NULL.
work - application defined function to be invoked on target dispatch queue 7 can’t be NULL.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason behind using this async blocks is to have the background task.

> dispatch_async:

By using this block you can run a code block asynchronously

Eg.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates can be done only on main thread
    });
});
```

> dispatch_async_f:

Irrespective of the block in async task you can put your custom function to be performed in the background.

Eg:

```
void mainFunc(void) {} // your function
void callingFuncForAsyncTask(void*) { mainFunc(); } // new function which takes arguments for calling inside async_f

dispatch_async_f(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 0, &callingFuncForAsyncTask);
```

For more info and parameter details kindly refer:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452834-dispatch_async_f